# Zsh theme not working properly on OSX

Tags: macos, zsh

Just got started with zsh yesterday but I'm having a lot of trouble getting themes to work.
Here is what is showing on my ZSH prompt:

```
$fg[cyan][$fg[white] keithy $fg[cyan]] [$fg[white]~/Desktop$fg[cyan]] >$reset_color
```

My ~/.zshrc

```
source ~/.antigen.zsh

antigen theme jdavis/zsh-files themes/jdavis
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you add the specific problem to your question?

Comment: The problem is the prompt in zsh actually shows up with the first code I posted, instead of the actual colors they were supposed to represent.

Answer (score 7):

**TL;DR:** Corrected `.zshrc` is provided at the bottom. You might want to try it first, see it working, then come back to read the explanations.

---

Inspecting [`antigen.zsh`](https://github.com/zsh-users/antigen/blob/30098c1d9955b8548aa827588c0d2c9be077c6f2/antigen.zsh) and [`jdavis.zsh-theme`](https://github.com/jdavis/zsh-files/blob/4b988090c0f62e00edc80dc6cebe108a6ac086ff/themes/jdavis.zsh-theme), it looks like you have two problems:

1. You haven't loaded and executed the [`colors` function](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/User-Contributions.html#Other-Functions) anywhere. Add

   ```
   autoload -U colors && colors
   ```

   to your `.zshrc`.
2. `PROMPT` is single-quoted and not parsed. You need to use the [`PROMPT_SUBST` option](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Options.html#index-PROMPT_005fSUBST) option to parse the prompt string. Add

   ```
   setopt promptsubst
   ```

   to your `.zshrc`. What the option does, according to the linked documentation:

   > If set, *parameter expansion*, *command substitution* and *arithmetic expansion* are performed in prompts. Substitutions within prompts do not affect the command status.

So your `.zshrc` should look like

```
source ~/.antigen.zsh
autoload -U colors && colors
setopt promptsubst
antigen theme jdavis/zsh-files themes/jdavis
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to use a prompt with color codes from [Oh-my-zsh](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh), and perhaps you haven't defined those colors. Try <s>adding the [`spectrum.zsh`](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/blob/master/lib/spectrum.zsh) file from Oh-my-zsh (if you don't want to run the entire package) to your source list, or</s> (not sufficient, see comments) redefining the colors in your prompt to default [zsh colors](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Zsh#Colors). You can play with the colors using the `spectrum_ls` function defined in `spectrum.zsh` or by changing numeric values in this one-liner (051 is a bright cyan):

`zsh -c 'print -P -- "%F{051}Hello, World%f"'`

Here is an example of a prompt without the colors defined (top), and a prompt where Oh-my-zsh has been sourced prior to defining `PROMPT` (bottom): 
[image: Zsh prompt examples]

#### Edit:

See the answer by [4ae1e1](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1944784/4ae1e1) for the individual requirements (Oh-my-zsh automatically sets them).

Comment: That file neither loads the necessary module nor sets the necessary option, so I wouldn't imagine it to work. I also use `oh-my-zsh` though, just for the record.

Comment: Whoops, you're right. I learned zsh with Oh-my-zsh from the start and am only now pulling apart what is considered "default" zsh. Thanks.

Comment: I'm also far from understanding Zsh in its entirety. Using it mainly as an interactive shell rather than a scripting language (bash for that), I also lack understanding of many things, so long as it works; oh-my-zsh does a good job hiding the hard stuff. Hopefully I'll figure out some time to really learn it from ground up.

Comment: I'm doing the same. Rewriting (and splitting up) my `.zshrc` helped quite a bit, but obviously I'm still unaware of some intricacies. Ah, well, live and learn…

Answer (score 0):

`PATH` is single quoted by default, and is not parsed because of this. Rewrite the var with double quoted string

```
PATH="$PATH"
source ~/.antigen.zsh
antigen theme jdavis/zsh-files themes/jdavis
```